# Explanation of a substitution in $\int \sqrt{8 - x^2} \mathrm{dx} $.

Tags: calculus

I saw that substitution should be $u = \arcsin \frac{x}{2^{3/2}}$, but i can't see how can i come to that conclusion. I'd appreciate a little push in the right direction.

Comment: $x=\sqrt8\sin(u)$

Comment: You can do it in two steps: first $x=\sqrt{8}t$, which turns the square root into $\sqrt{8}\sqrt{1-t^2}$; now $u=\arcsin t$ will do. Put the steps together…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we were to substitute $f(u)=x$, well, we want to express $$\sqrt{8-f(u)^2}$$ in some nice kind of function.  note that we have to insure that $$8-f(u)^2=g(u)^2 \iff f(u)^2+g(u)^2=8$$ For functions $f,g$ whose integral and derivatives are simple and well known, and $f^{-1}$, the inverse of $f$ exists on the domain of $x$.

The simplest of this is $f(u)=2\sqrt{2} \sin u$, $g(u)=2\sqrt{2} \cos u$ .

So since we have substituted $f(u)=2\sqrt{2} \sin u=x$, this implies that $$u=  \arcsin \frac{x}{2^{3/2}}$$
And we see that the integrate evaluates nicely. This is why we use this substitution.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the domain of the $\sqrt{8 - x^2}$. Now i see how it works.

Comment: Always glad to help.

Comment: First, i didn't know what you mean, but now i accepted it! :)